# Is there any legal way a state could secede?

Tags: united-states

Is there any way a state could legally secede from the United States?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

After the Civil War the Supreme Court ruled that the Acts of Succession of the southern states were unconstitutional. That is, they were and had always been part of the United States even if they said they weren’t.

So, a Constitutional amendment that allows secession would need to be passed granting that right. This would be similar to Article 50 of the Treaty on European Union that allowed the UK to leave the EU.

There would need to be a way of determining the exact process because all states contain a *lot* of Federal installations with some western states being more than half Federally owned. This could be in the amendment but, more likely, it would simply empower Congress to determine the process.

Is this legal? Absolutely. Is there any real chance of this happening soon? Absolutely not.

Comment: I guess this answer is not wrong, but the answer to the OP is currently “No.” As you say, a constitutional amendment could be passed (note: and ratified) to make it legal, but at this time it is not.

Comment: Link to ruling would be very interesting and informative.

Comment: @Damila it's not even clear that a constitutional amendment is necessary.  If congress agreed with the secession then nothing in the constitution would prevent it.  The precedent of the civil war only applies to unilateral secession.